# Allow NULL in a WPF Extended Toolkit DecimalUpDown control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-extended-toolkit

I have a property on my view model of type `decimal?`. NULL should be a valid value for this property, but when I erase the text from the DecimalUpDown control, a validation error occurs and the property is not given the value NULL (whatever it was previously remains).

The control is declared in xaml like:

```
<xctk:DecimalUpDown ValueChanged="UpDownBase_OnValueChanged" Text="{Binding ServiceSize}" Minimum="0" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="5" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}"/>
```

It will bind correctly if I enter a number
[image]

But as soon as the number is erased a validation error occurs, and the value can't be set back to NULL (in this case the model still has "5" as the value for "ServiceSize").
[image]

Validation.GetHasError() returns true for this control. Can I remove the Validation Rules entirely somehow?

Comment: You can try using IValueConverter to handle null input in-case you are using data binding.

Comment: @Ephraim I tried that before but I guess I didn't do it correctly as I got it working after rewriting the converter from scratch. If you add an answer some sample code I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement an IValueConverter to handle empty input.

```
public class DecimalUpDownValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // handle input on a case-to-case basis
        if(value == null)
        {
            // Do something
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Do the conversion from model property to DecimalUpDownValue
        return value;
    }
}
```

On your view: (Assuming you added the DecimalUpDownValueConverter as a static resource)

```
<xctk:DecimalUpDown ValueChanged="UpDownBase_OnValueChanged" Text="{Binding ServiceSize, Converter = { StaticResource DecimalUpDownValueConverter }}" Minimum="0" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="5" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}"/>
```

Comment: If you want empty input to be parsed as null, in ConvertBack use `return string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value) ? null : value;`